# How to filter EntityJoinWorldEvent so that its only triggered when you the player (not others) join?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I feel weird having posted a few questions so close to each other, but yeah uhh title says it all, once again. And yes I know there is a better way of doing this, I'm just making a client-side mod. Here's my code:

```
public class MainGuts
{
public static final String MODID = "farmhelper";
public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

@EventHandler
public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
{
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
}
@SubscribeEvent
public void CEntityJoinWorldEvent(EntityJoinWorldEvent event)
{
    if (event.entity != null && event.entity instanceof EntityPlayer)
    {
        event.entity.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText("Hey! I see your using my mod! Pretty pog ngl."));
    }
    //System.out.println("I haseth been called!");
    return;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code ? Also, a `entity instanceof Player` don't do the job ?

Comment: "How to filter EntityJoinWorldEvent so that its only triggered when you the player **(not others)** join?"

Comment: that triggers every time a player joins I wanna make it so it only triggers when its you who joins.

Comment: oh, you mean only yourself ?

Comment: yes (extra chars so it will let me post this)

Comment: You can check the UUID and/or the name

Comment: oh, so I could just grab the uuid of the player then check it for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239004/discussion-between-codingwiz-and-elikill58).